# ghostscript DejaVu font error

Tags: pdf, fonts, undefined, ghostscript

I'm having trouble with GhostScript 8.71 on Ubuntu 10.04. I'm trying to make a jpeg of a     particular PDF file which has the DejaVu fonts embedded within it.

The PDF file I'm trying to convert to a jpeg:

http://litesitev2.propserver7.com/bad_fonts.pdf

The ghostscript command I run:

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -o _tests/jpegs/aaa.jpg -dJPEGQ=75 -r216 _tests/bad_fonts.pdf
```

The error I get in ghostscript is:

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.71 (2010-02-10)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Error: /undefined in --run--
Operand stack:
   --dict:5/14(L)--   F1   10.5   FontObject   --dict:8/8(L)--   --dict:8/8(L)--   481       --dict:8/8(L)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2       %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1       %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3       %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--       %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --    nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --    nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --    nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1158/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:108/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:288/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:25/40(L)--   --dict:1158/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:10/10(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I downloaded all DejaVu fonts from http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download and put them in **/usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Font** but that still has no effect.

My search paths for ghostscript are:

```
Search path:
   . : /usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Init :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/lib :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/Resource/Font :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts : /var/lib/defoma/gs.d/dirs/fonts :
   /usr/share/cups/fonts : /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts :
   /usr/local/lib/ghostscript/fonts : /usr/share/fonts
```

Could anyone please help me solve this problem? Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably update to a more recent version of Ghostscript, 8.71 is more than 3 years old, the problem has likely been fixed by now. The file certainly works with current code.

Comment: May I ask how to do this in Ubuntu 10.04? I've tried apt-get update, then apt-get install ghostscript, but it just tells me im on the latest version (8.71). Thank you.

Comment: If your distribution isn't carrying the latest release then you'll need to get the source and build it yourself. You can get the source from http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Comment: How will this affect the current installation of GS? I'll need to do this on a live production server so this makes me very nervous! ;-)

Comment: You can maintain two installations, or replace the existing one, its up to you.